# No Consigo guardar el texto del formulario en la table texto

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy realizando unas pruebas en las que pretendo recorrer unos formularios con varios textos, en los que consigo traerme la información correctamente, pero a la hora de modificar y guardarlo no me lo esta haciendo correctamente, os dejo parte del código.

Controlador

```
   public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //

        $textos=Texto::findOrFail($id);

        $textos->update($request->all());


        $textos->save();

        Toastr::success("Se ha actualizado correctamente la $textos->texto");

        return Redirect::to('entradas');
    }
```

Vista

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Editar Textos</h3>
                </div>
        @foreach($textos as $listado)

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="box box-primary">

            {{ Form::model($listado, ['method' => 'post' , 'files' => true , 'route' => ['entradas.update',$listado->id]]) }}
            @method('PUT')

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::label('texto', 'Texto') }}
                    {{ Form::textarea('texto', $listado->texto, array("class" =>"form-control")) }}
                </div>

                    <div class="box-footer">
                        {{ Form::submit('Guardar', array("class" => "btn btn-primary")) }}
                        {{ Form::reset('Reset', array("class" => "btn btn-primary")) }}
                    </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach     
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un detalle acá y es que el método update no se utiliza así, de acuerdo a la documentación [Laravel Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#updates) se puede utilizar el método save tanto para crear como para actualizar, en tu caso quieres editar todas las propiedades de la entidad con lo que te llega de la petición del form, para ello hacemos uso del método fill como lo explican acá [Asignación en masa de propiedades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
$textos->fill($request->all());
```

Debes tener en cuenta que para que eso funcione la entidad debe tener una propiedad llamada "fillable" que es un array con el nombre de los campos que pueden ser editados, de lo contrario no se modificará nada de la misma:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Texto extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['texto'];
}
```

Luego de modificar las propiedades se salva la entidad:

```
$textos->save();
```